# How can I use a folder of common files in two different projects in Qt?

Tags: qt4

I am making two different projects in qt and there are 3 .cpp files are common between them, so how can I use that files in both the projects?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a [*subdirs* project](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-creating.html#adding-subprojects-to-projects) in Creator (named P1 in the following), and split the files from the first project into a project specific (A) and a common (C) subproject. Usually A is an application project that depends on C, C can be a static or dynamic linked library.

To set up the second project (B) you have two choices:

1. Add a second application project to the main *subdirs* project and make it depending on C, too:

   ```
   P1
   |-A
   |-B
   --C
   ```

   The directory structure can be kept simple and mirror that of P1:

   ```
   MyProjects
   --P1
     |-A
     |-B
     --C
   ```

   A and B will be built together and you'll be forced to keep them up to date with the current state of C. You must pass on P1 completely to your co-developers, and the subprojects are best be kept in a common VCS repository.
2. Create a separate *subdirs* project (P2), making the second project a subproject, and include the existing common subproject:

   ```
   P1
   |-A
   --C

   P2
   |-B
   --C
   ```

   You best keep each subproject in a separate directory hierarchy:

   ```
   MyProjects
   |-P1
   | --A
   |-P2
   | --B
   --C
   ```

   A and B can be built and passed on separately, each including C. You must take care to keep them up to date with C (hint: you can open more than one main project in Creator). You may be able to use separate repositories for P1, P2 and C, depending on which VCS you use, but that's a different question. I'm not sure if Creator's VCS integration supports setting this up, so you may have to do it manually once.